# Crack under the rim of toilet

Tags: toilet

I bought brand new toilet from faucet.com.

I see the crack under the rim of the toilet, see attached picture. Does this kind of crack pose any risk using the toilet ?

[image]

Comment: Would return it for being defective.  Probably not that major of a defect and could be seal up, but should not be there.

Comment: That looks like a pretty substantial crack, right at a spot that will see... a lot of action. It's also a great place for all sorts of nasty stuff to accumulate. This unit arrived defective, and you should send it back.

Comment: Zooming in on the picture, the right hand side of the crack seems to have some repair stuff(caulking/binding) in it.  Not if it is stuff added or just how the crack looks.

Answer (score 1):

That would not be a cosmetic surface scratch.

Clearly a manufacturing defect, or transportation damage.

I know it is big and heavy to handle, but would recommend to return/exchange it.

There is no way to tell if the crack will continue over time.